# Entry in Gauss' Mathematisches Tagebuch (Mathematical Diary)

Tags: mathematics, gauss

Does someone have a reference or further explanation on Gauß' entry from May 24, 1796 in his mathematical diary (Mathematisches Tagebuch, full scan available via https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/DE-611-HS-3382323) on page 3 regarding the divergent series
$$1-2+8-64...$$
in relation to the continued fraction 
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{1+\frac{2}{1+\frac{8}{1+\frac{12}{1+\frac{32}{1+\frac{56}{1+128}}}}}}}$$

He states also - if I read it correctly - *Transformatio seriei* which could mean *series transformation*, but I don't see how he transforms from the series to the continued fraction resp. which transformation or rule he applied.

The OEIS has an entry (https://oeis.org/A014236) for the sequence $2,2,8,12,32,56,128$, but I don't see the connection either.

Can anyone help or clarify?

Comment: Do we agree that the intended continuation of the series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot2^{\frac12 n(n+1)}$? (The triangular numbers seem to have occupied Gauß' mind a lot.) The sum converges $2$-adically, but not to a rational number, and I have not heard of Gauß preconceiving $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: Perhaps related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction

Comment: Agreed @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: There could indeed be a connection, but I can't see it, do you?

Comment: crossposted (with an answer): https://mathoverflow.net/q/334869/11260